# Get UTC offset in Ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime

I'm trying to get the UTC offset for a datetime.  The datetime is saved as:

> Fri, 31 May 2013 15:19:08 EDT -04:00

What I'd like to get is `"-04:00"`.  When I do `object.utc_offset`, I get `-14400`.  What function should I use?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are looking for [`strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime):

```
Time.now.strftime("%:z")
```

That will give you the offset such as "-04:00".

Comment: I found I needed to use the ':' flag 'to use colons for %z'. (Ruby 1.9.3) I.e. Time.zone.now.strftime("%:z") => "+01:00"

Comment: Side-note, the UTC offset is different from the time-zone. Multiple time-zone's share the same UTC offset. And a single time-zone's offset will change based on daylight savings.

Answer (score 3):

Its in seconds.  Divide by 3600 for hours, or 60 for minutes.

But if you want the formatted offset string, use vgoff's answer.

Answer (score -1):

vgoff and Matt Johnson beat me to it, but for further elaboration see page 717-720 and table 27.18 in *Programming Ruby 3rd Edition* (The Pickaxe book), for further elaboration.  **%z** gives hour offsets, **%Z** gives the time zone name, e.g. MDT, PST, etc.